# How to place title “inside” the image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

I am trying to customize the [Magnific Popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) plugin for my own purposes but it is missing a feature that I would like to use.

How I can place title with a counter of browsing images into the image modal?

Something like this:

[image: http://lmoroney.blob.core.windows.net/articleshots/jQueryLightbox/2-4.png]
<sub>(source: [wedesignpixel.com](http://wedesignpixel.com/wp-content/roundup/jquery-lightbox/images/jquery-lightbox-plugins%20%2813%29.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You could solve it with programming ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put the text you want under the `<img>` tag by just adding a `<p>` under the image in the modal div. However, adding buttons and other functionality like that is up to you and I don't believe it is provided in the plugin

Take a look at some of the examples on the website and look at the source code, you can do this in most browsers through the developer screen or via a plugin like FireBug.

Comment: ok thanks I want to make it with comments else so best way is make inline type.